# Swift : could not find an overload for executeUpdate that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to convert some Objective C code to Swift. However, I am running into an issue. I am getting the error  "Could not find an overload for executeUpdate that accepts the supplied arguments"

Swift

```
 var result : Bool = self.mEGODataBase?.executeUpdate(queryStr)!
```

Objective C

```
BOOL result = [self.mEGODataBase executeUpdate:queryStr];
```

Here is the executeUpdate method.

```
- (BOOL)executeUpdate:(NSString*)sql;

  var queryStr : NSString = "string"
```

I actually figured it out. It's

```
 var result : Bool = self.mEGODataBase!.executeUpdate(queryStr).
```

I needed to use an exclamation mark and not a question mark even though swift recommended me to use it. I believe this had to deal with optional chaining.

Comment: Have you tried using `queryStr as NSString`?

Comment: What's the queryStr? A String?

Comment: queryStr is a NSString.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `executeUpdate()` is even executing?
You're using Optional chaining .? this means that the function `executeUpdate()` will never be executed if `mEGODataBase` is `nil`

Please try this code:

```
var queryStr = "string"
var result = false
if let db = self.mEGODataBase {
   result = db.executeUpdate(queryStr as NSString) // casting shouldn't be necessary as String is already bridge to NSString, but try with and without and see how it goes.
   println("the result is: \(result)")
} else {
   println("mEGODataBase is Empty")
}
```